# Weird compilation error

Tags: errors, subscripts

Why is it that

```
\[
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}}f(v,w) \\    
\]
```

compiles for me, despite the extra `}`, but

```
\[
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}f(v,w) \\    
\]
```

does not?

Edit: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13, pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2013.3.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always post *complete* documents:

I get an error on both lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}}f(v,w)    \\
\]

compiles for me, despite the extra \}, but

\[
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}f(v,w) \\    
\]

does not?

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.8 ...um_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}
                                                  }f(v,w) \\
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.14 ...m_\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}
                                                  f(v,w) \\
? x
No pages of output.
```

with an error on lines 8 and 14.

The error is a missing `{` after the `_`

This produces no error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_{\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}}f(v,w)   
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll keep the complete documents thing in mind. Also, I was under the impression that one **entity** counted as the same, for example `a_\mathrm{min}` is valid. Why is this different?

Comment: @HameerAbbasi `\mathrm` is designed so that works (athough it is bad style:-) the `{}` are required but the expansion of `\mathrm` _includes_ the brace. Compare `A_\foo` with `\newcommand\foo{abcd}` or with `\newcommand\foo{{abcd}}` one gets subscript `a` the other `abcd`